# fake http post request - viewstate

Tags: c#, http, post, request, viewstate

I am trying to fake a post request to a site programmed with c#.
I used WireShark to sniff the communication between my computer and the server.

I noticed that the client send **viewstate** data (encoded in Base64) and I would like to know how to fake it in my request.

my post code

```
 public static void sendPostRequest(string responseUri,CookieCollection responseCookies)            
        {
            HttpWebRequest mPostRequest =
                (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://tickets.cinema-city.co.il/webtixsnetglilot/SelectSeatPage2.aspx?dtticks=" + responseUri + "&hideBackButton=1");
            mPostRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36";
            mPostRequest.KeepAlive = false;
            mPostRequest.Method = "Post";
            mPostRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            CookieContainer mCookies= new CookieContainer();
            foreach (Cookie cookie in responseCookies)
            {
                mCookies.Add(cookie);
            }
            mPostRequest.CookieContainer = mCookies;
            HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse2 = (HttpWebResponse)mPostRequest.GetResponse();  
        }
```

Comment: Fiddler and [XSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)...

Answer (score 0):

If you can "fake" signed/encrypted data you don't really need to deal with fake posts - just steal all SSL traffic :).

View state comes in original response for the page encrypted - so you simply need to parse original response (use Html Agility Pack) and send that view state back in post request.